# creating a vector from multiple data.table inputs in R

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am trying to create a vector that contains concatenated information from a `data.table` called `runVars`:

```
runVars
    calculationType calculateHCC cutOffTime historyCutOff numberOfHistroicalYears
 1:        COMPLETE         TRUE          9         FALSE                       1
 2:        COMPLETE         TRUE          9         FALSE                       2
 3:        COMPLETE         TRUE          9         FALSE                       1
 4:        COMPLETE         TRUE          9         FALSE                       2
 5:        COMPLETE         TRUE         10         FALSE                       1
 6:        COMPLETE         TRUE         10         FALSE                       2
 7:        COMPLETE         TRUE         10         FALSE                       1
 8:        COMPLETE         TRUE         10         FALSE                       2
 9:        COMPLETE        FALSE          9         FALSE                       1
10:        COMPLETE        FALSE          9         FALSE                       2
11:        COMPLETE        FALSE          9         FALSE                       1
12:        COMPLETE        FALSE          9         FALSE                       2
13:        COMPLETE        FALSE         10         FALSE                       1
14:        COMPLETE        FALSE         10         FALSE                       2
15:        COMPLETE        FALSE         10         FALSE                       1
16:        COMPLETE        FALSE         10         FALSE                       2
```

the vector I want to create should look something like this:

```
 [1] "histyears1_hcc1_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hcc1_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears1_hcc1_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hcc1_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE" 
 [5] "histyears1_hcc1_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hcc1_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears1_hcc1_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hcc1_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE"
 [9] "histyears1_hcc0_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hcc0_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears1_hcc0_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hcc0_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE" 
[13] "histyears1_hcc0_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hcc0_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears1_hcc0_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hcc0_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE"
```

I have created this vector using a data.table approach:

```
setDT(runVars)
runVars[,runName := paste0("histyears", numberOfHistroicalYears, "_hcc", as.integer(calculateHCC),
                  "_histcut", as.integer(historyCutOff), "_", cutOffTime, "m_", calculationType)]
subset <- runVars$runName
```

However, i do not like this very much, it seems somehow clumsy. I was opting for the `lapply()`, but i cannot figure out what is wrong with it?

```
subset <- lapply(runVars, function(x){
  paste0("histyears", x$numberOfHistroicalYears, "_hcc", as.integer(x$calculateHCC),
                  "_histcut", as.integer(x$historyCutOff), "_", x$cutOffTime, "m_", x$calculationType)
})
```

> Error in x$numberOfHistroicalYears :    $ operator is invalid for
> atomic vectors

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you share the data in a copy&pasteable format? IMHO your first approach seems pretty straightforward. You might consider `sprintf` instead of `paste` which might be more elegant.

Comment: That error stems from the fact that `lapply` runs over your columns (vectors that are the `x` in your function) and you cannot use `$` on a vector. `do.call(paste0, ...)` is the right approach in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is correct you should not use `lapply` here.

Here is another variation with `sprintf` which might be shorter.

```
library(data.table)
runVars[,runName := sprintf("histyears%s_hcc%d_histcut%d_%sm_%s",
           numberOfHistroicalYears, as.integer(calculateHCC),
           as.integer(historyCutOff), cutOffTime, calculationType)]
runVars$runName

# [1] "histyears1_hcc1_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hcc1_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE" 
# [3] "histyears1_hcc1_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hcc1_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE" 
# [5] "histyears1_hcc1_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hcc1_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE"
# [7] "histyears1_hcc1_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hcc1_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE"
# [9] "histyears1_hcc0_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hcc0_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE" 
#[11] "histyears1_hcc0_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hcc0_histcut0_9m_COMPLETE" 
#[13] "histyears1_hcc0_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hcc0_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE"
#[15] "histyears1_hcc0_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hcc0_histcut0_10m_COMPLETE"
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer... also using `sprintf()`, but slightly different approach

```
#setup sprintf-string
string_format <- "histyears%s_hcc%s_histcut%s_%sm_%s"
#what columns to use
cols <- c("numberOfHistroicalYears", "calculateHCC", "historyCutOff", "cutOffTime", "calculationType")
#run
DT[, do.call(sprintf, c(.SD, fmt = string_format)), .SDcols = cols]
# [1] "histyears1_hccTRUE_histcutFALSE_9m_COMPLETE"   "histyears2_hccTRUE_histcutFALSE_9m_COMPLETE"  
# [3] "histyears1_hccTRUE_histcutFALSE_9m_COMPLETE"   "histyears2_hccTRUE_histcutFALSE_9m_COMPLETE"  
# [5] "histyears1_hccTRUE_histcutFALSE_10m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hccTRUE_histcutFALSE_10m_COMPLETE" 
# [7] "histyears1_hccTRUE_histcutFALSE_10m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hccTRUE_histcutFALSE_10m_COMPLETE" 
# [9] "histyears1_hccFALSE_histcutFALSE_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hccFALSE_histcutFALSE_9m_COMPLETE" 
# [11] "histyears1_hccFALSE_histcutFALSE_9m_COMPLETE"  "histyears2_hccFALSE_histcutFALSE_9m_COMPLETE" 
# [13] "histyears1_hccFALSE_histcutFALSE_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hccFALSE_histcutFALSE_10m_COMPLETE"
# [15] "histyears1_hccFALSE_histcutFALSE_10m_COMPLETE" "histyears2_hccFALSE_histcutFALSE_10m_COMPLETE"
```